# Remove empty strings from library(stringr) in R

Tags: r, string, vector, stringr

I have a vector of string named words, and I need to remove all empty strings using `library(stringr)`. I tried `str_remove_all(words, pattern = "")`, but it showed me:

> Error: Empty `pattern`` not supported.

What should I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 5):

How about just use a subset in base R:

```r
words <- words[words != ""]
```

If perhaps your "empty" words are not really empty, but actually contain one or more whitespace characters, then use `grepl` to remove them:

```r
words <- words[!grepl("^\\s+$", words)]
```

Comment: maybe an additional `trimws` would be great

Comment: Everyone, please note, using `"^\\s+$"` does not remove the really empty strings. If you want to replace whitespace-only strings AND empty strings you need `"^\\s*$"`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `grepl` solution be simpler like this: `grep("^\\s*$", xn, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)`. It's not as explicit but it's benchmark is a bit better.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use `stringr`, then you probably want to use `str_subset`, which removes elements of a vector, instead of removing the match from each element. Here is a pattern that keeps only strings with at least one character:

```
str_subset(words, ".+")
```